# Using GetElementsByTagName in C# Windows Form with XML

Tags: c#, xml, getelementsbytagname

I'm loading a xml page from a secured website which i want to read with Xml Document.

A part of the xml:

```
<ActueleVertrekTijden>
  <VertrekkendeTrein>
    <RitNummer>5070</RitNummer>
    <VertrekTijd>2015-03-20T19:42:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
    <EindBestemming>Den Haag Centraal</EindBestemming>
    <TreinSoort>Sprinter</TreinSoort>
    <RouteTekst>Lage Zwaluwe, Dordrecht, Rotterdam C.</RouteTekst>
    <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
    <VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">6</VertrekSpoor>
 </VertrekkendeTrein>
 <VertrekkendeTrein>
    <RitNummer>1971</RitNummer>
    <VertrekTijd>2015-03-20T19:50:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
    <EindBestemming>Venlo</EindBestemming>
    <TreinSoort>Intercity</TreinSoort>
    <RouteTekst>Tilburg, Eindhoven, Helmond</RouteTekst>
    <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
    <VertrekSpoor wijziging="false">4</VertrekSpoor>
    <Opmerkingen> // This is not always available, but it is important and specific for a 'VertrekkendeTrein'
      <Opmerking>Rijdt vandaag niet</Opmerking>
        </Opmerkingen>
    </VertrekkendeTrein>
```

Now i'm using the following code:

```
string urlo = "the website";
            string resultje = HttpGeto(urlo);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(resultje);

            XmlNodeList ns = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("VertrekkendeTrein");



    //MessageBox.Show(ns[0].InnerXml); //*This part works it shows the xml inside the first "VertrekkendeTrein"*

    //*Now I want to read all the items of ns[0] and split it like: GetElementsByTagName("RouteTekst")*

                XmlDocument xd1 = new XmlDocument();
                xd1.LoadXml(ns[0].InnerXml);
                XmlNodeList nsvertrektijdje = xd1.GetElementsByTagName("RouteTekst");
                var vty1 = nsvertrektijdje[0].InnerText;
                MessageBox.Show(vty1);
```

The problem which i'm having now is that I can't load ns[0].InnerXml in LoadXml. It gave no result.

Edit:

Now i'm using the following:

```
string urlo = "website";
            string resultje = HttpGeto(urlo);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(resultje);

            XmlNodeList ns = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("VertrekkendeTrein");

            var element = ns[0] as XmlElement;
            XmlNodeList nsvertrektijdje = element.GetElementsByTagName("RouteTekst");
            var vty1 = nsvertrektijdje[0].InnerText;
            MessageBox.Show(vty1);
```

But it still doesn't work

Comment: Not an answer but you should definitely check out XDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since the ns[0].InnerXml doesn't have a root node , you are unable to parse the inner xml.
try appending a temp node while you loading xml

```
xd1.LoadXml("<data>" + ns[0].InnerXml + "</data>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `InnerXml`, as that does not include the `VertrekkendeTrein` node, so it is not a valid xml document (A document can only have a single root node).  You could use `OuterXml`, but that is wasteful, as you have already parsed the XML.

Your best route here is to cast the `XmlNode` to an `XmlElement` and use the `GetElementsByTagName` method from that.

```
var element = ns[0] as XmlElement;
XmlNodeList nsvertrektijdje = element.GetElementsByTagName("RouteTekst");
```

The full code now looks like this:

```
var xml = @"<ActueleVertrekTijden>
<VertrekkendeTrein>
    <RitNummer>5070</RitNummer>
    <VertrekTijd>2015-03-20T19:42:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
    <EindBestemming>Den Haag Centraal</EindBestemming>
    <TreinSoort>Sprinter</TreinSoort>
    <RouteTekst>Lage Zwaluwe, Dordrecht, Rotterdam C.</RouteTekst>
    <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
    <VertrekSpoor wijziging=""false"">6</VertrekSpoor>
</VertrekkendeTrein>
<VertrekkendeTrein>
    <RitNummer> 1971 </RitNummer>
    <VertrekTijd> 2015 - 03 - 20T19: 50:00 + 0100 </VertrekTijd >
    <EindBestemming> Venlo </EindBestemming>
    <TreinSoort> Intercity </TreinSoort>
    <RouteTekst> Tilburg, Eindhoven, Helmond </RouteTekst>
    <Vervoerder> NS </Vervoerder>
    <VertrekSpoor wijziging = ""false""> 4 </VertrekSpoor>
    <Opmerkingen>   // This is not always available, but it is important and specific for a 'VertrekkendeTrein'
    <Opmerking> Rijdt vandaag niet</Opmerking>
   </Opmerkingen>
</VertrekkendeTrein></ActueleVertrekTijden>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList ns = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("VertrekkendeTrein");
var element = ns[0] as XmlElement;
XmlNodeList nsvertrektijdje = element.GetElementsByTagName("RouteTekst");
var vty1 = nsvertrektijdje[0].InnerText;
MessageBox.Show(vty1);
```

Comment: I changed my code but still nothing happens, Do I have to change `var vty1 = nsvertrektijdje[0].InnerText;` ?

Comment: No, taking my modifications in your code worked fine for me in my testing.  I updated the answer to include my full test code.